# Makefile: Weird escaping anomaly in target defined within function

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

So, I'm defining a target for each module built in an Android project.

```
define apicheck_target
$(eval MODULE_NAME = $(1))

.PHONY: apicheck_module_$(MODULE_NAME)

apicheck_module_$(MODULE_NAME): $(ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT)/module_path_mapping
    $(info module specific)

endef

$(foreach m,$(ALL_MODULES), \
    $(eval $(call apicheck_target,$(m))) \
)
```

Since "$(info module specific)" above is not escaped, it executes immediately when the function runs and the dependency has not yet been processed.

However, if I escape this ("$$(info module specific)") then I start getting duplication/override errors:

```
vendor/proprietary/build/tasks/apicheck.mk:25: warning: overriding commands for target `apicheck_module_liboemcrypto_32'
vendor/proprietary/build/tasks/apicheck.mk:25: warning: ignoring old commands for target `apicheck_module_liboemcrypto_32'
vendor/proprietary/build/tasks/apicheck.mk:25: warning: overriding commands for target `apicheck_module_libnvfnet_32'
vendor/proprietary/build/tasks/apicheck.mk:25: warning: ignoring old commands for target `apicheck_module_libnvfnet_32'
vendor/proprietary/build/tasks/apicheck.mk:25: warning: overriding commands for target `apicheck_module_libnvfnetstoredefog_32'
vendor/proprietary/build/tasks/apicheck.mk:25: warning: ignoring old commands for target `apicheck_module_libnvfnetstoredefog_32'
```

It doesn't make sense. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that each module name appears only one time in the `ALL_MODULES` macro?  I recommend you modify your `foreach` loop to replace the `eval` with `info`.  That will cause make to print out the text it would be evaluating.  It's often pretty clear what the problem is.

Comment: Some are, but the entries I care about are not duplicated.

Comment: If any are duplicated you'll get this error for those.  Look at the output from the `info` debug method I mentioned.

Comment: Like I said. None are duplicated.

Comment: No, you said "some are".  There's nothing in the makefile you've shown that treats "the entries you care about" any differently than the others: the makefile walks through every value in `ALL_MODULES` and creates targets for them.  If any are duplicated you'll get errors.

Comment: The ones I care about do not belong to the set that are duplicated.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can be miscommunicating here: I'm trying to say a very simple thing: if you have duplicate words in `ALL_MODULES` then given the makefile you've shown here, you will get _overriding commands_ errors.  That's it.  Make has no idea which words in `ALL_MODULES` you care about and which you don't.  It just expands them all.  In any event, I've described what you need to do to debug your problem; I copied your example above, added a setting for `ALL_MODULES`, and it worked as expected with no warnings about overriding commands.  So, we can't help without more details.

Comment: ALL_MODULES does not duplicate the entries that I care about. Make, on the other hand, is somehow interpreting that all of the targets are duplicated. So, we are generating mostly unique targets and yet Make is having a problem with all of them.

Comment: Your attitude is not necessary and not helpful. I'm just answering your questions. If you're not getting what you need to answer a question then either be more patient or stop responding.

Comment: My responses are perfectly civil.  You've asked for help but haven't usefully engaged with the only person who's offered it, and I've spent a non-trivial amount of time trying.  So, I'll choose... option #2.  I hope you figure out your problem.